# Setting android rating bar to nearest half stars from float variable

Tags: java, android, variables, ratingbar

I have looked around for a solution to this, but could only find answer that set it as actual numbers not as variables.

I would like the rating bar to display the same number of stars as a score out of 5 going up in 0.5s, so it is is possible to get 3.5 etc.  I can set individual float values for the rating bar, but cannot use a variable for the same thing, it just rounds it to the nearest integer.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    RatingBar bar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1); 
    bar.setNumStars(5);
    bar.setStepSize(0.5f);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score= b.getInt("score");
    //change the score out of ten to star rating out of 5
            float scores = score / 2;
    //display star rating
    bar.setRating(scores);
```

Any help would be received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Score needs to be set as a float, not an int.  As an int it is rounded, so the only thing you need to change is 
float score = b.getInt("score")l